# How can I use Case Statement inside join in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

So, basically I need to achieve this effect, any suggestions?

```
JOIN ((CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(e.order_id) FROM entry ee WHERE ee.order_id = o.id) > 1
           THEN (SELECT * FROM entry e WHERE e.user_id = 3 )
           ELSE (SELECT * FROM entry e WHERE e.user_id = 3 AND e.draw_id = (SELECT dd.id
                                                      FROM draw dd
                                                      WHERE dd.draw_date_time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)
                                                      ORDER BY dd.draw_date_time ASC
                                                      LIMIT 1))
           END) e ON e.order_id = o.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Not how you do it.  Put the conditions in the `on` clause.  If I follow the logic correctly:

```
JOIN
(SELECT e.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ee.order_id) as cnt
 FROM entry e
) e
ON e.order_id = o.id and
   e.user_id = 3 and 
   (e.cnt <= 1 or
    e.draw_id = (SELECT dd.id
                 FROM draw dd
                 WHERE dd.draw_date_time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)
                 ORDER BY dd.draw_date_time ASC
                 LIMIT 1
                )
```

I suspect this can be simplified further.  Without the context of the larger query and an explanation of what the logic is supposed to do, it is hard to make suggestions.  You might want to ask another question.